# Glide slide breakpoints has no effect

Tags: javascript, breakpoints, glidejs

I built several slides in the same page with [Glidejs](https://glidejs.com/docs/):

```js
import Glide, { Controls, Autoplay, Keyboard } from '@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm';

let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('g-related');

for (const c of slides) {
  let gid = '#' + c.id;
  let dur = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1000);

  new Glide(gid, {
    type: 'carousel',
    autoplay: 10,
    animationDuration: dur,
    animationTimingFunc: 'linear',
    hoverpause: true,
    perView: 5,
    breakpoints: {
      1024: {
        perView: 4,
      },
      600: {
        perView: 3,
      },
    },
  }).mount({ Autoplay })
}
```

And I use breakpoins [as said in docs](https://glidejs.com/docs/options/#breakpoints). All the slides work, but the breakpoints don't work. Why? (`hoverpause` doesn't work neither).

### Aditional info (code in context)

**JS:**

https://github.com/aitormendez/futurabasura/blob/main/web/app/themes/fb/resources/scripts/singleProduct.js#L47-L67

**HTML:**

https://github.com/aitormendez/futurabasura/blob/main/web/app/themes/fb/resources/views/woocommerce/single-product/related.blade.php#L62-L73

**Working example in staging server (scroll to bottom):**

http://fb.e451.net/shop/ill-e-t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot import Breakpoints from ESM modules:

```
import Glide, { Controls, Autoplay, Keyboard, Breakpoints } from '@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm';
```

Then:

```
mount({ Autoplay, Breakpoints })
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed how I imported Glide and missed this part.

Comment: Btw if you're importing keyboard, then probably want to mount it too. Right?